# What is the mod-$3$ analogue of the solution to the Eventown problem?

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, reference-request, extremal-combinatorics

The following so-called "Eventown" problem is a classic chestnut:

> The $n$ people of Eventown like to form clubs, subject to the following requirements:
>   (1) Each club has an even number of members.
>   (2) Each pair of clubs has even intersection.
>   (3) No two clubs have exactly the same membership.
>   What is the maximum number of clubs eventown can possibly have?

You can construct $2^{\lfloor n/2\rfloor}$ clubs by thinking of the town as consisting of $\lfloor n/2 \rfloor$ pairs of people (possibly with one person left out).  Each club then consists of some subset of the pairs of people.

As it turns out, this is optimal, and there's a slick proof using linear algebra: To each club we associate a vector in $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$, where the vector is $1$ in position $i$ if person $i$ is in the club.  The first two conditions then correspond to the statement that any two club vectors are orthogonal.  So if $W$ is the subspace spanned by the club vectors, $W$ is contained in its orthogonal complement, so $\dim(W) \leq \lfloor n/2 \rfloor$, which then gives an upper bound on the number of vectors in $W$.

---

I presented this problem (along with the corresponding "Oddtown" problem) in our Math Club this week.  In the discussion afterwards, someone had the following question: What happens if we replace "even" by "divisible by $3$" everywhere?

If you work over $\mathbb{Z}_3^n$ instead of $\mathbb{Z}_2^n$ (making each club vector $1$ in position $i$ if person $i$ is in the club, $0$ otherwise), the linear algebra still goes through, and an $n/2$ dimensional space still contains at most $2^{n/2}$ vectors from $\{0,1\}^n$, so you have the same upper bound as before.

On the other hand, the analogue of the lower bound construction (put people in groups of $3$, with each club consisting of some number of groups) now gives $2^{\lfloor n/3 \rfloor}$.  So there's now a gap between what the two arguments give.

Which (if either) of the bounds is tight here?  An equivalent way of stating it:

**What is the maximal size of a collection $A_1, A_2, \dots, A_k$ of subsets of $\{1, 2, \dots, n\}$ such that both $|A_i|$ and $|A_i \cap A_j|$ are always divisible by $3$?**

In this language it feels like this has to be a well-known problem in extremal set theory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, this problem is open, and actually has been for some time.

[Frankl and Odlyzko](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0195669883800146) considered the more general question of how many subsets you can choose so that the intersection sizes are always divisible by some $\ell \geq 2$.  Assuming the existence of a Hadamard matrix of order $4 \ell$ (which is known to exist for $\ell \leq 166$), they constructed a collection of $(8 \ell)^{\lfloor n/4 \ell \rfloor}$ sets having all intersections divisible by $\ell$.

In terms of my original question, this corresponds to giving a lower bound that is roughly 
$$24^{n/12} \approx (1.30)^n \approx 2^{0.38 n}$$
So in particular, the trivial "trios" construction is *not* optimal.

They also show that for $\ell \geq 5$, the $2^{n/2}$ bound from the linear algebra method is not optimal.  However, I still don't know of any better boudn for the case $\ell=3$.